# Why would someone use regression analysis to compute weighted variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, factor-analysis

I stumbled upon a measure that uses multiple regression analysis to compute weighted variables, instead of factorial analysis or other more common methods. I have a feeling this is just bad statistics but would like to know if anyone agrees with me, or whether there indeed is any reason behind this method. Please help me understand!

Description of the method: 
There are 80 questions, that form 16 subtraits and 4 supertraits. Subtraits are standardized means, and they form 4 groups, that each represent one supertraits in general. The manual says "to compute a weighted score for the supertrait, multiply each of the subtraits by its weight for its supertrait. Weights are determined by conducting a multiple regression analysis, in which subtraits predict supertraits. We have essentially ignored the regression weights for the 'children' of a 'parent' supertrait, choosing to give the children equal weights."